# perform double click on an element in protractor-cucumber

Tags: protractor

syntax for double click on an element which is working in all browsers.
I am using protractor version 5.2.2 and cucumber 3.2.0
I tried with below code.but it is not working for me

```
var AddButton = element(by.css(".frx-memberlist-grid-container tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) span"));
browser.actions().mouseDown(AddButton).mouseUp().perform();
browser.sleep(1000);    
browser.actions().mouseMove(AddButton).click().perform();
```

and

```
element(by.css(".frx-memberlist-grid-container tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) span")).click();
element(by.css(".frx-memberlist-grid-container tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) span")).click();
```

and

```
browser.actions().doubleClick(browser.element(by.css(".frx-memberlist-grid-container tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) span"))).perform();
```

Comment: The latter approach looks fine except that `browser.element(...)` - why not just `element(...)`?

Comment: I have tried with  browser.actions().doubleClick(element(by.css(".frx-memberlist-grid-container tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) span"))).perform();  but that also not work for me.

Comment: anyone having any idea?

Comment: The code that i have used : browser.actions().doubleClick(browser.element(by.css(".frx-memberlist-grid-container tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) span"))).perform();  is working in IE and Chrome but not in Firefox.Do any one know how it works in Firefox.

Comment: I am using the Firefox 57.0.4 (64-bit). and selenium 2.53.1.Is there any issues with these versions?